# Ganglia - gmond + gmetad work, gweb does not

Tags: ganglia

I have created an installation of Ganglia on a RHEL 6.5 EC2 instance. I have gmond, gmetad, and gweb all installed and configured on this host. I am only trying to monitor the localhost for now. I have the localhost configured to be the data source. When I go to `http://localhost/ganglia2`, I get an ‘Unable to connect’ page in Firefox. Any idea why?

When I run `telnet localhost 8649` and `telnet localhost 8651`, I get XML dumps without any problems.

When I run `telnet localhost 8652`, I get this output:

```
‘Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.’
```

So it seems the connection is there, but the web interface still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my gmetad.conf file:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7707627/

Here is my gmond.conf file:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7707632/

Answer (score 0):

I think at one point the URL was `http://localhost/ganglia2` but now the URL is `http://localhost/ganglia`, did you try that?